# actionPerformed cannot see reference variable for JButtons

Tags: java, swing

I've been trying to get two buttons to work. 
However it seems that actionPerformed cannot see my buttons.

Things I've tried:
- checking my import statements, they seem to be correct
- checking for missing parentheses
- checked if I put the actionPerformed in the constructor by accident
- checked acces modifiers 
- checked variable names

So far I'm lost at why it can't solve the symbols for button1 and button2.

Please help?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;



public class Wisselscherm
        extends JFrame
        implements ActionListener {




    public Wisselscherm(Wisselkoers wisselkoers){

        String munt1 = String.valueOf(wisselkoers.getMunt1().getNaam() );
        String munt2 = String.valueOf(wisselkoers.getMunt2().getNaam() );
        setTitle(munt1 +  " - " + munt2 + " Converter" );


        setSize(500,500);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

       String teken1 = String.valueOf(wisselkoers.getMunt1().getTeken() );
       JLabel munteenheid1 = new JLabel(teken1);
       add(munteenheid1);


       JTextField textf1 = new JTextField(10);
       add(textf1);

       JButton button1 = new JButton(">>");
       add(button1);
       button1.addActionListener(this);

       JButton button2 = new JButton("<<");
       button2.addActionListener(this);
       add(button2);


       String teken2 = String.valueOf(wisselkoers.getMunt2().getTeken() );
       JLabel munteenheid2 = new JLabel(teken2);
       add(munteenheid2);

       JTextField textf2 = new JTextField(10);
       add(textf2);


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == button1) {
            System.out.println("Button1 is pressed");

        } else if (e.getSource() == button2) {
            System.out.println("Button2 is pressed");
        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your buttons are defined as local variables to the `Wisselscherm`'s constructor, so they will not be accessible outside of it's context

## You could...

Make them instance variables, which would allow them to be accessible from within the whole class

## You could...

Use [anonymous listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), which would allow you to associate a individual listener with each button, meaning that you can gurentee what triggered the `ActionListener`

## You could...

Make use of the `actionCommand` property of the `JButton` and `ActionEvent` to decouple the listener from the source of the event, allowing you to re-use the `ActionListener` with other buttons/actions which generate the same `actionCommand`.

By default, the `actionCommand` will be the text of the button if it's not otherwise set directly

## You could...

Use the `Action` API

All in or, you should probably have a closer look at [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details

Comment: Okay, someone is going to have to explain to me the purpose of the downvote. Since no other answers have been downvoted, I can only assume you have issue with my answer. In what ways does it not answer the OPs question?  In what ways could it be improved? Since no new answers have been provided, I can only assume you have no idea of how to answer the question either, which begs the question of how do you know this answer isn't correct

Comment: Meh, don't sweat the down-votes. You've got 2 up-votes to counteract it, one from me.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Always looking to improve - can't please everybody :P

Comment: That's why I don't even try.

Comment: Wow, a lot more anwser than I thought I would get. Thanks! (I can't upvote yet, else you'd get one)

Comment: @Jaqen Glad it could help

Answer (score 2):

This is a scope problem, just move `button1` and `button2` to the Class's scope level:

```
public class Wisselscherm extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;

    ...
```

Then you can have:

```
button1 = new JButton(">>");
```

(Note that I removed `JButton` word in that line)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for the edit, I didn't see the code issue before :)

Comment: But then I would double declare them?


Trying it your way, I get an : Cannot Groovy files error.

Comment: @Jaqen please see the edit. So, the answer is no, you don't declare twice

Comment: Nope, the program still bugs out.

Error:Cannot compile Groovy files: no Groovy library is defined for module 'Java13'

Hmmm (not using Groovy, never touched it)

Comment: The error is somewhere else then :) Both (this and MadProgrammer's) answers solve the issue you're having here

Comment: Hm, I'll give it another shot tomorrow, thanks for the help though!

Comment: Yeah it was the scope. Thanks!