# How to make multiple buttons on a GUI work

Tags: java

Im creating a GUI program with multiple buttons. I'm only able to use one of the buttons at the moment. Here is my Button Listener class. I want to be able to use the "Test" button and then use the "Yes" or "No" button after. Let me know if you need to see any more of my code.

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==TestButton)
        {

            TestWord = (Text_Input.getText());

            StringBuilder RevTestWord = new StringBuilder();
            RevTestWord.append(TestWord);
            RevTestWord = RevTestWord.reverse();

            DisplayText = "Is " + RevTestWord + " a real word?";    
            Test_Anadrome.setText(DisplayText);

            if(e.getSource()==YesButton)
            {
            DisplayText = "Word added to Anadrome list.";
            Test_Anadrome.setText(DisplayText);
            }

            if(e.getSource()==NoButton)
            {
                DisplayText = "Type a different word and press the 'Test Word' Button.";
                Test_Anadrome.setText(DisplayText);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Sorry I'm pretty new to Java.

Comment: i usually set the id of each button to a unique number or enum so i can do a switch avoiding a bunch of if statements.

Comment: Hello, Alyssa, I think it would be good to edit your question to add a tag for whatever graphics library you are using. Other people with similar issues could find your question more easily that way.

Comment: [More then one way to skin this cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912584/actionperformed-cannot-see-reference-variable-for-jbuttons/42912699#42912699)

Comment: usually you will implement an ActionListener for each button, but seems like you want to share this ActionListener with multiple buttons, it would be good to show us how you are using this class as well

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your if/else statements for your `YesButton` and `NoButton` are inside of your if statement for `TestButton`, so as a result those statements are only being checked if `source==TestButton`. Try moving this code outside of the if statement:

```
            if(e.getSource()==YesButton)
            {
            DisplayText = "Word added to Anadrome list.";
            Test_Anadrome.setText(DisplayText);
            }

            if(e.getSource()==NoButton)
            {
                DisplayText = "Type a different word and press the 'Test Word' Button.";
                Test_Anadrome.setText(DisplayText);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all your testing at the same level.  The nested ifs are causing problems.  And remember to use if/else.  No sense in continuing to do other checks if the previous one succeeds.

You can also set the `ActionCommand` which is a String.  For components that use the `actionListener`, you can do for example `button.setActionCommand("mycommand")`.

Then in the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` you can do

`String cmd = e.getActionCommand();`

That allows you do discern between buttons or other components without having direct access to their instance.

If you don't set the ActionCommand it defaults to the button's text.